# Nodejs SSL for SockJS + Express

Tags: node.js, ssl

I've got a simple `SockJS` and `Express` server in `nodejs`. Now id like to add `SSL support` for these servers.

Here is my server code:

```
var sockjs = require('sockjs');
var my_http = require("http");
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');


var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('test/keys/key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('test/keys/cert.pem')
};

// Create a service (the app object is just a callback).
var app = express();

// Create an HTTP service.
http.createServer(app).listen(8008);
// Create an HTTPS service identical to the HTTP service.
https.createServer(options, app).listen(443);


var echo = sockjs.createServer({
    log: function (severity, message) {}
});
echo.on('connection', function (conn) {

    conn.on('data', function (message) {
        conn.write(message);
    });

    conn.on('close', function () {

    });
});

var server = my_http.createServer();
echo.installHandlers(server, {
    prefix: '/echo'
});
server.listen(8081, '0.0.0.0');

var server_https = my_http.createServer(options);
echo.installHandlers(server_https, {
    prefix: '/echo'
});
server_https.listen(443, '0.0.0.0');



app.get('/type/:channel', function (req, res) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.send("Hello");

    res.end();
});
```

Problem is that i get the `port already in use error`:

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE
```

I've got Nginx listening on 443 otherwise my site would not work on ssl.

Any ideas how to set this up?

Answer (score 0):

Inside of your nginx config you should have your port listed in 'upstream'. In your case you probably have the same port listed under server. It shows that error when you do that. See below for proper configuration (If you change "listen 80" to "listen 8000" you'll see that error):

```
    upstream app_yourAppName {
        server 127.0.0.1:8000;
    }

    # the nginx server instance
    server {
        listen 80;
        ...
        ...
    }
```